# Dynamically added TableRows not visible in TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I've been trying to dynamically add TableRows for each item in a set of dialogue, but the rows aren't showing up. When stepping through the debugger, I can see the number of children on the TableLayout increase, but afterward none show up.

Adding rows to TableLayout dialogue

```
List<Dialogue> content = post.getDialogue();
for (int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++) {
    Dialogue d = content.get(i);
    TableRow tr = (TableRow) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_post_dialogue_include, dialogue, false);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    TextView label = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.label);
        label.setText(d.getLabel());
    TextView dialogueLine = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.dialogue_line);
        dialogueLine.setText(d.getPhrase());
    dialogue.addView(tr);
}
```

Layout containing TableLayout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    style="@style/title" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialogue"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/title" />
```

TableRow layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:gravity="top" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialogue_line" />
```

Comment: try setting the height(>= 10px) and visibility to true, see if that helps

Comment: i think you should try some thing like 

newrow = dialogue.newrow()

Comment: A parent class was hiding the container. Modifying that made it visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

instead !!

Comment: fauxriginal did you have any success with @smanandhar's solution? I have the same problem.